# How to add global finder in dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces in my web application and I need to add a search option in to dataTable.

The dataTable contain about 10 pages (using pagination)

Is it possible to add a global finder something like the global filter

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

Thanks

Comment: whats the difference between the both ? what you want to achieve with the finder that you can't with the filter?

Comment: I was under the impression that the filter will filter only the match records on the current page while finder will go over all the table

Thanks